# How can I get a column in a DataGridView to autosize to the contents of a Combobox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a column in a DataGridView with the column type [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) . In this combo box, I have several strings of varying length.  Some of these strings can be changed by the users in the application settings.  It looks something like this:

[image: screenshot of column]

The column AutoSize options, such as AllCells, work nicely with DataGridViewTextBoxColumns.  But they don't work as expected with combo boxes.

How can I set the width of this column to fit the contents of a combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate width of items using [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the width of column to maximum value of the items width.

To change width of column use [`Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width(v=vs.110).aspx) property of column. To change only width of dropdown menu, use [`DropDownWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.dropdownwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
// I suppose your column is at index 0
var c = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
c.Width = c.Items.Cast<Object>().Select(x => x.ToString())
    .Max(x => TextRenderer.MeasureText(x, c.InheritedStyle.Font,
        Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.Default).Width);
```

You can put above code in `Load` event handler of your form or in other places which you may want to reset the size of column.

Note: In above example items of combobox are supposed to be of type of string. But you can use any type of items and extract text of items. The key point here is using `TextRenderer.MeasureText` with that parameters.

**VB Version**

```
Dim c = DirectCast(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
c.Width = c.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(x) x.ToString()) _
            .Max(Function(x) TextRenderer.MeasureText(x, c.InheritedStyle.Font, _
                Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.Default).Width)
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: `TextRenderer` was the class name I was missing.  That's a nice way to do this. But it's not quite complete!  It ignores the dropdown arrow and some internal padding. By trial and error, I determined that my particular display settings (font size of 14, all else at defaults) require an additional 22 pixels for padding.  That's enough for this project!

Comment: Yes, you may need add some additional spaces like padding and etc. Also take a look at [`DisplayStyleForCurrentCellOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaystyleforcurrentcellonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property for column. It indicates  whether the `DisplayStyle` property value applies only to the current cell in the `DataGridView` control when the current cell is in this column.